# Getting row number in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollviewdelegate, nsindexpath

when i use

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
     NSArray *visibleCells = [my_table visibleCells];
```

i want to know the number of the row (in my_table) that is visible (with visibleCells).

For example, if i do

```
[visibleCells count];
```

i know that there are 5 rows visible, but i need to know the real number (for example: number 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 in the table view).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can call indexPathForCell: on the table view with the first and last objects of the array to get the two index paths.

Comment: thanks you but... how can i call indexPathForCell: for one specific cell? and how can i sei the NSIndexPath?

Answer (score 0):

solved!

using this

```
UITableViewCell *currentCell = [visibleCells objectAtIndex:i];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tabella_gallery indexPathForCell:currentCell];
```

works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I use

```
func loadImagesForVisibleRows() {

    // Get the visible cells indexPaths
    let indexes: Array = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()!

    // Loop through them to determine whether visible or not
    for index in indexes {

        let row = index.row
        // Do what you need to do

    }
}
```